# Need to get a single record based on latest date in the 3rd colum

Tags: date, sort

I want to get a single record for each value in the first column
there three records below have value of 2019-10-20 as the latest date, in this case first we get the three rows, then latest date of the last column  which is 2019-10-14
so we get that record as the output

INPUT:

```
150098517|000000601706|2019-10-19|2019-10-10|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098517|000000635671|2019-10-20|2019-10-20|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098517|000000637002|2019-10-20|2019-10-19|1265457733|2019-01-14
150098517|000000645047|2019-10-20|2019-10-18|1265457733|2019-01-12
150096747|000000645048|2019-10-17|2019-10-17|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098555|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098554|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098523|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098523|000000645194|2019-10-14|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
```

OUTPUT:

```
150098517|000000637002|2019-10-20|2019-10-19|1265457733|2019-01-14
150096747|000000645048|2019-10-17|2019-10-17|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098555|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098554|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098523|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
```

Thanks,
Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a file called `file`:

```
$ sort -t '|' -k3,3r -k6,6r file | sort -t '|' -u -k1,1
150096747|000000645048|2019-10-17|2019-10-17|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098517|000000637002|2019-10-20|2019-10-19|1265457733|2019-01-14
150098523|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098554|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098555|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
```

This first sorts the the data on the 3rd `|`-delimited field in reverse order (most recent dates first).  For equal dates, the 6th field is used for the sorting.

The intermediate result from this first call to `sort` looks like this:

```
150098517|000000637002|2019-10-20|2019-10-19|1265457733|2019-01-14
150098517|000000635671|2019-10-20|2019-10-20|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098517|000000645047|2019-10-20|2019-10-18|1265457733|2019-01-12
150098517|000000601706|2019-10-19|2019-10-10|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098523|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098554|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098555|000000645194|2019-10-18|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
150096747|000000645048|2019-10-17|2019-10-17|1265457733|2019-01-13
150098523|000000645194|2019-10-14|2019-10-16|1265457733|2019-01-13
```

The result of this is then sorted on the first field while removing lines that are duplicates in terms of this first field.  Since the data coming into this second sort is sorted on the dates in the 3rd and 6th fields, the lines that are discarded as duplicates will have earlier dates.